# How to hide hover tooltips on Spyder 4

Tags: python, windows-10, spyder

not sure where to ask:

**is there a way to not have the help tooltip/popup/hover window opening in spyder?**

since updating to 4.0 the window does not close when you change between windows:[image: screenshot of the problem]

guess something like this will be reported and delt with in future updates but for now i would be happy to just disable it

(using 64-bit windows-10 machine)

Comment: As soon as you pause while entering code, a tooltip of some sort appears, including the one which says "I can't help, no documentation available". Now you're forced to interact with this tooltip, usually you press ESC to continue typing your code, else unwanted actions are triggered by the tooltip. This behavior is specific to Spyder, any other editor looks for some key to start interacting with the tooltip (e.g. TAB), other keys just close the tooltip and are used by the editor. In Spyder all tooltips must be all deactivated, unless you like pressing ESC after any pause.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Yes, there is. You need to go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Introspection`

and deactivate the option called `Enable hover hints`.

**Note**: The issue you posted above with the hover not hiding when giving focus to other applications will be fixed in our next bugfix version (4.1), to be released in a couple of months.

Comment: Thanks. Since I can communicate with the _maintainer_ straightaway, my humble suggestion: could it not be better placed at `Tools > Preferences > Editor` along with `Show tab bar` or `Show line numbers` (as `Show tool tip`)-- which I hope would be more intuitive and easier found out ?

Comment: Sorry, we understand it's confusing but for now we're not planning to do that because it'd require a major internal refactoring of our code.

Comment: I like these hover hints, but I have to disable them because they appear way too quickly and steal focus when I'm trying to do things like double-click. Is it possible to delay them to 3000 ms instead of instantly popping up?

Comment: That's a very good point! Could you open an issue about it in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues)? Thanks!

Comment: I had to restart Spyder for the change to take effect (I'm using Spyder `5.0.0`).

Comment: I was hoping that this answer would help, but it appears that I am experiencing a (related?) problem similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66506773/2988730 in Spyder 4.1.5. @CarlosCordoba any chance you could take a look at that question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thanks for the ping. This option only works for our Editor, but the OP of the question you referenced wants to disable hints in the console. I'll left answer there about that.

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me mad. Still an issue for me in 4.2.2 though