# How to disable constant popups in Spyder's console

Tags: python, spyder

I need to get rid of these constant popups in Spyder. They are so frustrating to me. They constantly get in the way of what I am typing, and I can't see the code. I unchecked everything in Tools-Preferences-Linting.

[image]

Comment: Please add some info about your spyder version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide hover tooltips on Spyder 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225879/how-to-hide-hover-tooltips-on-spyder-4)

Answer (score 7):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The options in "Completion and linting" only work for the Editor. Since you want to disable those hints for the Console, you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Display`

and deactivate the option called `Show calltips`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helps. I also have the same issue in the editor. Assuming that one of the linter options changes that? Or should I post another question?

Comment: I thought I had answered that before, but I couldn't find it among my answers. So, please open a new one and give me a ping so I can point you in the right direction. That way it'll be useful for other people as well.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68402127/2988730. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, no offense but I also find these completion tips to be very distracting. That said, they are certainly not unique to Spyder.

Comment: That's why we provide an option to disable them.