# How to disable (or move) hover documentation in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

How do I disable the hover documentation boxes in Spyder?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou0wt.jpg)

My main problem with these boxes is that they block where I'm writing (although that is not a problem in the picture over). So if I could change the position, that would also solve my problem.

(This is essentially the same question as
[How to hide hover tooltips on Spyder 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225879/how-to-hide-hover-tooltips-on-spyder-4),
but I didn't have enough points to comment on that question.)

I'm using Spyder 4.0.1.

I tried to uncheck the "Enable hover tips"-option under Tools - Preferences - Completion and linting - Introspection, but they are still there, see the picture under.

I have also tried to restart Spyder, but the hover boxes still appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide hover tooltips on Spyder 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225879/how-to-hide-hover-tooltips-on-spyder-4)

Comment: @GonçaloPeres users saying he already tried this ..But deosn't worked..

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66506773/7109869)?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres No, neither of them do. I've tried the first (which is the same question, but following the answer doesn't help) and the other is about IPython, not the editor-part in Spyder, where I have my problem). But thanks for the suggestions!